# How could I avoid WYSIWYG buttons to follow the link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build an editor. Once I click an any button ( bold, or italic,...) it follows the link.  Here is what I have tried out.

```js
function execCmd(command) {
  document.execCommand(command, false, null);
}

function execCommandWithArg(command, arg) {
  document.execCommand(command, false, arg);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="text_section">
    <button onclick="execCmd('bold');"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('italic');"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCommandWithArg('createLink', prompt('Enter a RUL','http://'));"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('unlink');"><i class="fas fa-unlink"></i></button>

    <div class="p-2" contenteditable="true" id="content_text" style="border:solid; width:200px; heigth:100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Post text" id="submit" class="btn py-3 px-4 btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>
```

How could I use `e.preventDefault();`  function on it ?
This code lines seem to work as expected, but the problem is not solved in my programm. 
I think `e.preventDefault();` might solve the problem. 
Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback needs to return false.

Try

```
<button onclick="execCmd('bold'); return false;">
```

Or

```
<button onclick="return execCmd('bold');">

function execCmd(command)
{
    document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `button` element is inside a `form` element it acts as `submit` unless it's `type` attribute say different (etc: reset, button).

So a quick fix will be to set `type="button` to your editing buttons:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="execCmd('bold');">
    <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
</button>
```

Enjoy code!